# Which kernels from Ubuntu 3.5.0 can I remove?

Tags: boot, kernel

After reading some very helpful information on your forums, I now know how to remove unneeded kernels to free up disk space for updates.

Can any of you tell me which of the following I can safely uninstall?

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 834K Oct  9  2012 abi-3.5.0-17-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 834K Nov 13 18:19 abi-3.5.0-19-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 837K Dec 11 19:26 abi-3.5.0-21-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 837K Jan  8 22:11 abi-3.5.0-22-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 837K Jan 24 13:34 abi-3.5.0-23-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 839K Feb  7 06:02 abi-3.5.0-24-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 839K Feb 25 19:32 abi-3.5.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 839K Mar  8 23:49 abi-3.5.0-26-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 841K Mar 25 20:29 abi-3.5.0-27-generic
```

I have already removed `3.5.0-17-generic` as, after a brief search, I found it was tagged as deleted.